# Whether it is okay to dichotomise a 4-point Likert-scale outcome item

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, linear

I'm using an already collected data-set within my research, meaning I was very limited with the outcomes that I could use. One of my two main outcome variables was an item using a 4-point Likert-scale (‘How often do you feel unhappy at school’ (1=all of the time to 4=never)). My supervisor previously asked me to dichotomise this variable, combining the response options ‘all of the time’ and ‘most of the time’, creating ‘high negative affect’, and combining ‘some of the time’ and ‘never’, creating ‘low negative affect ’. Though, I am having huge difficulties justifying in my paper why I dichotomised this variable. It may because only a small proportion of the participants had answered some of the response options e.g. 315/11,717 had answered one of the response options. Though, I'm not sure if this is enough reason to dichotomise it. I would really appreciate any support if anyone knows other reasons that she may have suggested to dichotomise it, or ways that I can justify this decision in my paper (my supervisor is on holiday and so I can't ask them).

Thank you so much all for your support in this, I really do appreciate it! I am just adding a bit of other information as some were asking for more details regarding why my supervisor may have asked me to do this. Judging from my notes, what she had said was that if you had a 3-level variable, you essentially calculate the odds of being at each level, as in that is what doing a linear regression would do (though mine is a 4-level variable so not sure if this also applies to this) and that it would not be ideal, and so making the variable binary would be a better option. Even at the time, she had said we would need to justify it conceptually and statistically and that perhaps I could try and find something about the dimensionality vs non-dimensionality of this construct, but she never really explained further than this.

Comment: You are being reasonable with your skepticism; binning tends to be discouraged.

Comment: As a gen;l policy, I agree w/ @Dave, but would like more detail. Do you have any insight why your supervisor wants to 'collapse' the data? Is this supposed to make it easier to analyze the data? Or is there a feeling that "1&2" are "Sad" and "3&4" are "Happy", which amounts to saying there's a huge difference between "2&3"? (An alternative view might be that "2&3" both really mean something like "silly question, can't decide".) // More briefly, this seems a crucially important issue to you. Can you explain why? What would be wrong with analyzing the data both ways to see what happens?

Comment: Loss of power is a concern.

Comment: By definition, Likert scales have five points, not four. It would be more accurate to describe your info as *Likert-type scales* or, more simply, scaled data.